# How to solve "Document was unloaded during execution (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)"

Tags: c#, selenium, protractor-net

I'm trying to update our Selenium tests to work with the latest Firefox. This code snipet shows how I initialize the Driver. Instance is a class member: NgWebDriver Instance

```
FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOptions.SetPreference("marionette", true);

IWebDriver NonProtractorInstance = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);


Instance = new NgWebDriver(NonProtractorInstance);
Instance.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
Instance.IgnoreSynchronization = false;
```

However, the following code fails:

```
Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(/* URL to angular page */);
```

With this following error: 
Document was unloaded during execution (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

Note this particular URL does redirect to another page, but both original and redirect page are angular pages.

I've tried every variation of initializing the drivers I could find and they all failed with similar errors.

Any one have any other things I can try to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor actually does not support FF > v47